# Build URL that opens file (.doc/.docx etc office files) in office client application in browser

Tags: 2010, office-web-apps

Currently struggling with the issue of how to build a URL which will redirect you to the new tab opening document in its native application.

For example `wordviewer.aspx` is taking care of word files. I know that with search results I am able to get the url in the format like `/_layouts/wordviewer.aspx?querystring`, but how to construct it from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the id parameter to your querystring and put the relative path there:

```
/_layouts/WordViewer.aspx?id=/myweb/MyLibrary/MyDoc.docx
```